# Помогите определить границы сказуемого.

Tags: синтаксис

Там сладостней звучит поток, 
Там соловей поет звучнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поток звучит,соловей поёт. Сравнить: звучит музыка.

Обстоятельства "сладостней, звучнее" распространяют сказуемое, но не относятся к нему и даже не связаны с ним тесно.

Сравнить: голос становился звучнее, сладостней, в этом случае выделяется именное сказуемое со  связкой "становиться", соотносимой со связкой "быть".